# SQL Database & Java - Invalid object name

Tags: java, sql, sql-server

it seems my code is not working. I am trying to extract data from microsoft NAV Cronus DB, but it appears JAVA can't find the table to print.

So I have 2 classes - DAL & Controller

DAL:

```
   import java.sql.*;

    public class DAL {

        private static String connStr = "jdbc:sqlserver://Localhost;Databases=CronusDB;user=root;password=root;";

        public static Connection getConn() throws SQLException {
            return DriverManager.getConnection(connStr);
        }

        public static ResultSet findEmployeeData() throws SQLException {
            Statement stmt; 
            stmt = getConn().createStatement();
            String sqlStr = "select [No_], [First Name], [Last Name], [Initials], [Job Title] from [CRONUS Sverige AB$Employee];";
            ResultSet rset = stmt.executeQuery(sqlStr);
            return rset;
        }
}
```

Connector:

```
import java.sql.*;

import t3.isprojekt.uppg2.dal.DAL;

public class Controller {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws SQLException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        DAL.getConn();
        System.out.println("Connection Success!");
        System.out.println(DAL.findEmployeeData());

    }

}
```

When trying to execute the code I recieve the following error:
Exception in thread "main" com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Invalid object name 'CRONUS Sverige AB$Employee'.

The problem is that the table does exist, and I have tried putting .dbo in front without success. Any ideas?

Comment: I hope you tried prepending `dbo.` and not `.dbo`.  Have you tried renaming the table to `abc` and seeing if `SELECT ... FROM [abc]` works?

Comment: Ah yes, of course the period is after, just a typo here on SO. dbo.[CRONUS....] that is.

Comment: yes, I get the same error... "Invalid object name 'dbo.abc'. So it seems it can't find any tables.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like the database is very sensitive to upper- & lowercase letters. The tables are listed as "CRONUS Sverige..." in MSSQLServer, but when copying the name directly into JAVA it is pasted as "CRONUS SVERIGE" (uppercase). So finally got this working!